# How to dynamically change styleUrls or style in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, styled-components

I want to allow users to customize colors and some styles in Angular application. For that I want to make something like this

**Structure:**

**component-one**

  folder-with-css-files
    style-for-component-1-for-client1.css
    style-for-component-1-for-client2.css
    style-for-component-1-for-client3.css
    style-for-component-1-for-client4.css

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.style-for-component-1-for-client{clientId}.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  clientId: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // pseudocode
    clientId = service.fetchClientId() // for example

  }
}
```

How I can achieve that? I want to have some css files for every component and depend on user id I want to assign them to styleUrls. Someone can tell me how to do it?

Comment: I'd say your best bet is to use SCSS variables and simply import themes for each client at build time using different build configs for each client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scss and wrap every stylesheet in a different class then based on the user’s selection change the class of your body.

Something like:

DarkMode.scss

```
.darkMode{
   your first css here…
}
```

LightMode.scss

```
.lightMode{
   your second css here…
}
```

index.html:

```
<body class="lightMode"></body>
```

Doing the above will by default apply the lightMode styling and if you remove the classes of your body in any of your components and replace it with darkMode then the darkMode styling will apply.

Adding/Removing class to/from body:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

addClass(){
    this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'className');
}

removeClass(){
    this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'className');
}
```

Adding/Removing the class does not have to be only in the index.html file, all you need to do is have a tag with a certain class that wraps around your whole code. For example in one of your components:

component.html:

```
<div [class]="className">
    the rest of your html here...
</div>
```

component.scss:

```
.greenDefault{
   green default css here...
}

.redDefault{
   red default css here...
}

.greyDefault{
  grey default css here...
}
```

component.ts

```
className: string;

changeStyle(class: string){
   this.className = class;
}
```

Comment: but I will be able to do change this css in every component? or just in main index.html?

Comment: The idea behind this is if you have 2 different css styles lets say dark mode and light mode, you wrap your whole css related to light mode in .light-mode class and for dark mode you do the same. Then inside your index.html file you add a default class to the body like: `<body class="light-mode"><app-root></app-root></body>`. Then anywhere in your code in any of the pages you can change the class of the body to change the theme of your application.

Comment: but I need to customize every component, not only main index.html

Comment: Yes I understand, but if you change the class of your body tag it will affect your whole application, so it does not matter if it is a component or anything else.

Comment: I updated my answer if it clarifies it better

Comment: Thank You for Your help :) anyway, I want to set every css in separate file. Could You tell me how to achive that?